# Reference images storing in android

Tags: android

I have developed an app for image comparison. now i am storing the reference images on sdcard
and the app is working fine. my problem is that.. if anyone removed the sdcard then the app will not be work. is there any method to store the reference images in the app itself so that any user can download and can use the app?? 
im using android 2.2

Comment: Yes. you can store the images in the res/drawable* folder and refer them from the code. Refer [this](https://github.com/madaan/Tarang/blob/master/src/com/bvp/miniproject/SplashScreen.java) as an example.

Comment: hey. there are several images i have to refer .. is there any other method.?

Comment: drawable contains only Displaying images like icon background images..ryte.? how can we refer files like  java .?